# Kernel exercise

Tags: self-study, svm, references, kernel-trick, online-algorithms

I'm looking for any good reference that can help me to understand the following exercises about kernels and online learning.

A training set $(x_1, y_1), ...,(x_m, y_m)$ is generic iff $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}_j \Rightarrow y_i = y_j$. Consider the following kernel function $K_a(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) := \prod^n_{i=1}(1 +(x_it_i) + (1 - x_i)(1 - t_i))$.

**1.** Argue that $K_a: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Kernel (I've already demonstrated that $K_a$ is a valid kernel)

**2.** Given a generic training set $(x_1, y_1), ...,(x_m, y_m) \in \{0,1\}^n \times\{0,1\}$ does there neccesarily exist a vector $\mathbf{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$
\sum^m_{j=1}\left(\sum^m_{i=1}\alpha_iK_a(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) - y_j\right)^2 = 0 ?
$$

Provide an argument to justify your answer.

**3.** Given a generic training set $(x_1, y_1), ...,(x_m, y_m) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ does there neccesarily exist a vector $\mathbf{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$
\sum^m_{j=1}\left(\sum^m_{i=1}\alpha_iK_a(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) - y_j\right)^2 = 0 ?
$$

Provide an argument to justify your answer.

*Is it in some way related to the representer theorem and/or the Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF) ? Thanks for your advice.*

**NOTE**: you can see where the question is formulated [here](https://mega.nz/#!1NZBXRQY!9Z3pafWFJcitcgcfZgfcC-cSl0yWLYia7Q9BPnPbunw)

Comment: Please use a more informative title.

Answer (score 1):

For both a) and b) you agree that if I find a generic training set and prove that there does not exist an alpha such that the formula you wrote equals 0, then I proved that given a generic training set $(x_1,y_1), \dots,(x_m,y_m) \in \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}$ there does not necessarily exist a vector $\alpha \in \mathbb R^m$ such that:

$$
\sum \limits_{j=1}^m \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_j) - y_j\right)^2 = 0
$$

?

You agree that if I prove that there does not necessarily exist such an alpha for a) then there does not necessarily exist such an alpha for b)? Just use the same training set provided for a) as for b).

So here is a generic training set:
$((1,0,0),(0)) , ((1,1,0),(1)), ((1,1,1),(1))$ where the first 3 numbers are an x and the second number in the parentheses is its corresponding y. Now lets compute all $K(x_i, x_j)$ for all i,j : $K_a(x_1 , x_1)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 0 + 1)(1 + 0 + 1) = 8$,  $K_a(x_1 , x_2)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 0 + 0)(1 + 0 + 1) = 4$, $K_a(x_1 , x_3)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 0 + 0)(1 + 0 + 0) = 2$, $K_a(x_2 , x_2)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 2 + 0)(1 + 0 + 1) = 8$, $K_a(x_2 , x_3)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 0 + 0) = 4$ , $K_a(x_3 , x_3)= (1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 1 + 0)(1 + 1 + 0) = 8$  . Is this correct?

Now for there to exist an $\alpha$ s.t. $\sum \limits_{j=1}^m \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_j) - y_j\right)^2 = 0$ since $\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_j) - y_j\right)^2$ is always greater than or equal to 0, we need it to be equal to zero for every single j. i.e. we need to show that :

$\forall j$ we have $ \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_j) - y_j\right) = 0 \implies  \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_j) = m * y_j$

So now consider the generic training set I provided. we need
$\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_1) = 0$ since $y_1$ is 0. Since the $K_a(x_i, x_1) > 0$ we need all of the alphas to be equal to zero. Ok so we set all of the alphas to zero.

But now consider $\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x_2) = 3$ (since $y_2$ is 1). We need now a different set of alphas for this equation to work. So we do not have an alpha which causes this equation to be zero.

If your question is a homework question and there are no mistakes in it, then it seems I am missing something, because then it would not make sense to ask a part b.

EDIT:
Does this question relate to the represntor theorem? The representor theorem tells us that the optimal solution to Kernel SVM has the form $w = \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \psi (x_i) $ which if you then plug into the form of the prediction which is $\langle w, x \rangle $ you get that a prediction has the form $\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_i K_a(x_i, x)$ on some input x . So the question is asking you to figure out whether the optimal solution is necessarily perfect, i.e. 0 error. I would imagine that in some cases the answer is yes and in some cases the answer is no. This question does not make sense to me because it seems unnecessary to ask both a) and b) if a) is not true. It would make more sense if a) was true and b) wasn't. Right now as the question is asked, it doesn't seem to directly relate to linear separability or DNF. Perhaps if the question was a) also had the condition that y was the output of a DNF formula applied to x, then it would. Or if in b) it was asking to assume the training set is linearly seperable. Then perhaps the question would make sense and be more interesting, although i have not thought about it too much.

Comment: And for $\alpha_i = 0$?

Comment: @user3494047 I think that where the x's in the training set are in $\{0,1\}^n$ the $K_a(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = 2^n$. On the other hand, even if your answer seems reasonable, it is not true then $\alpha_i = 0, 1\leq i \leq m$ and I still believe that there's something missing with the _generic_ property of the training set.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @user3494047 Thanks for your answer. The question has no mistakes (there is just an additional sentence saying: provide an argument to justify your answer). Maybe is good to recall that the question concerns online learning. On the other hand, I don't know if I'm wrong but your generic training set is not showing the property $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}_j \rightarrow y_i=y_j$. However, even if we add an additional example, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: yes, you could add another example that is identical to one that is already there. The main point of the generic training set is that you ***can't*** have two identical x vectors with two different y's.

Comment: @user3494047 Sorry, I figure out now that for part B, the generic training set is $(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{y}_1), ..., (\mathbf{x}_m, \mathbf{y}_m) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: yes but isnt the training set I provided in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: yes, indeed. I was checking if question has no mistakes

Comment: I think you got the third $K_a$ calculations wrong, ie:
$$K_a(x_2,x_2)=(1+1\cdot1+(1-1)\cdot(1-1))\cdot(1+1\cdot1+(1-1)\cdot(1-1))\cdot(1+0\cdot0+(1-0)\cdot(1-0))=8$$
The result is right though.

Comment: @user3494047 could you check the slide on page 13 [here](https://mega.nz/#!cFglSBgS!2f1QmU9ouwdEWfNfush5Ec7wPpj3da0F7BEG2EY_qA0). I think that it maybe needs to be demonstrated in terms of linear separable boolean functions

Comment: @user3494047 page 27 on the link above may also have some definitions to demonstrate the problem (k-term monotone DNF)

Comment: If this is a HW or text book question, perhaps you should post the entire question.

Comment: @user3494047 I updated my post question with the whole content of the problem

Comment: I edited my response to answer also your question of how it relates to the representor theorem

Comment: @user3494047 yes, I agree with your thoughts, but the context where the question is formulated makes me hesitate about how to demonstrate it. Maybe it would be good to have a look at the context [here](https://mega.nz/#!1NZBXRQY!9Z3pafWFJcitcgcfZgfcC-cSl0yWLYia7Q9BPnPbunw)

Comment: I see. Perhaps what you should do is make up a DNF formula over 3 variables and come up with a set 3-5 sample x's and see what the y would be if it was your DNF formula and see if in your example you can find an alpha which makes zero error. if yes try and figure out if its true for all DNF. Mostly this looks like a question where you should try a bunch of examples and use them to gain intuition as to why it maybe must be true or must not. Then do the same thing with linear separability for part b. But you can write that it is not true in general as shown by my example and many others.